# Port color theme from visual studio code to visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, themes, visual-studio-code, color-scheme

As part of the standard install Visual Studio Code comes with a color theme named "Monokai Dimmed".

Is there as way to port this to Visual Studio 2015?  I've checked the community themes (http://studiostyl.es/schemes) and i can't find it listed there.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Themes are build very differently in Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code, so it will need to be manually converted. I'm not aware of an existing converter but Visual Studio Code uses the TextMate `.tmTheme` (`.plist`) format for themes.

Related: it's been requested for [VSCode to import VS themes](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2529).

Comment: Thanks very much. Looks like I'll just have to get creative!